# Android games player's data backup

Tags: android

Let's say you have a game where you have an in-game currency and you (developer) want to save it and backup it in case switching to another device or hard-reset. So saving it using for example using `SharedPreferences` only isn't enough. I read about Saved Games API but I think it shouldn't be used in this case because player can manage these Snapshots and he can delete it. So may I use some cloud or own server? I am a bit confused because now I tested Swing and Dots games. You propably know them. I played some progress, unlocked some achievements and uninstalled game. Then I installed it again in attempt to see how they manage this situations. I was surprised that both games don't backup my progress and they started again from zero. Have you experienced this situations or do you have any tips? Why these well-known and famous games don't implement this behavior?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the user being able to manage their own data and delete it if they see fit...?

Comment: No it isn't  but I want to make it "transparently", behind the scenes. Would you recommend using Saved Games API?

Comment: Me? I don't know. I'm not an Android developer. But as an Android user I'd prefer for things to be visible and not hidden.